# get method isn't returning results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simply reproduce what is on the jquery site for the .get method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="foo">foo</li>
        <li id="bar">bar</li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('li').get());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should return

```
[<li id="foo">, <li id="bar">]
```

But all I get is `[object HTMLLIElement],[object HTMLLIElement]`

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Try my updated answer. I thought you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, select the `ul` element and display it's content with the `html` function:

```
alert($('ul').html());
```

`html` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> Description: Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: yes, just tried it and got this object HTMLLIElement], so the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is alright:

> The .get() method grants us access to the DOM nodes underlying each
>   jQuery object.

Get returns the DOM elements hold by the jQuery variable.
And when you output DomElements they become the form "HTMLLIElement".

Comment: so is there a way to reproduce what they have here:hmm.. http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: This IS what you get. Its just the output format, that differs. In fact, if you save your result, and check its length property afterwards, it will be 2.

Comment: Ok..the answer is:var j = ($('li').get(0));
alert (j.innerHTML);

Answer (score 0):

But that's what [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) does! It will retrieve the HTML DOM elements matched by the selector. If you want the jQuery objects, you should use just `$('li')`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not necessarily doing anything wrong.

What you're getting is the actual result of calling `toString` (which `alert` will do for you) on an array with 2 `<li>` DOM objects in it:

```
[object HTMLLIElement],[object HTMLLIElement]
```

However, what's mentioned in the [API Documents](http://api.jquery.com/get/) isn't a string representation of the array, but is meant as a description of the array's current state in memory:

```
[<li id="foo">, <li id="bar">]
```

It was meant just as a shorter way of saying something like this:

> The result is an array with 2 DOM objects that represent the `<li id="foo">` and `<li id="bar">` elements, respectively.

---

Now, if you actually want to get the markup in the alert, you'll have to [get the outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419877/15031) of the elements. Then try:

```
alert($('li').map(function () { return $(this).outerHTML(); }).get());
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmpwM/

Comment: You can just select the `ul` element and use the `html` function. see my answer.

Comment: @gdoron Yes and no. That may be all that's really necessary, but it results in a single string rather than an array of strings.